# on click over a link it should go to its address sliding instead of directly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In html code, when we click over a link it goes to its associated address.but when the address is on the same page we mention .now,it goes there but i want it to slide to that address rather directly jumping on that address.hope you understood my question.

Answer (score 0):

maybe what you mean is target blank in href..?

```
<a href="" target="_blank">Go New</a>
```

Comment: nooo. suppose my href is at top of my page. consider                              <a href="#contact">click</a>     where "contact" is an "id" and is located deep down on my page, So when i click on 'click' it goes to contact area.So now it directly jumps to that area but i want it to slide through till that area.